# New or Existing cell when using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Having a `UITableViewController`and using:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 
          indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    return cell
 }
```

**Using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:'' instead of`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`` how can I determine if a cell is a new one or a reused one?**

Comment: What do you need to do? You should really have a custom cell and do whatever it is there...

Comment: I want to setup things like background color only once.

Comment: Generally, all tables with the same reUseIdentifier are getting "ReUsed" - so if you want to change something (for example the Background Color) you could overwrite this (and set it to the standard value for all other rows) - but a better Idea is to make a new Row, with another ReUseIdentifier, and change here the color.

Ive tried lots of this (having at least 10 different layouts in 1 Table) and the best performance is if you make another cell with a different reUseIdentifier.

Comment: @derdida could you please provide some code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own custom cell class to use for the reuse identifier. Then, inside that cell, implement `awakeFromNib` and make your changes to the cell. This will only be called once when your cell is loaded from its NIB file.

Any other changes that need to be made when the cell is reused can be made in `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: Do you have an example what I would do in ``prepareForReuse``?

Comment: Not that often used, but if an image was loaded when the cell is show it could be removed here for example